# Incline Presses and Flyes for squarer chest

Tags: bodybuilding, bodyweight-exercises

Even though shape of pectorals are purely genetics. Few Body Builders suggested me to do Incline Presses and Flyes for building squarer chest. 
Are there any scientific evidence or research to to prove this?

Comment: How does a squared chest look like? You can surely trying to focus on size of certain muscle areas if using full range of motion but as you stated the look will depends on your genetics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there are any studies to show that those particular exercises will help build a “squarer chest” (whatever that may be).  However, I think the intent of the advice was to suggest that you should introduce **variation** into your training routine.

From [ExRx](http://www.exrx.net/ExInfo/TrainingPrinciples.html)...

> **Variation**
>
> A basic prerequisite for continued adaptation is variation.
>   Performance improvements will decrease if the same exercises and
>   training loads are continued for a prolonged period of time (AKA
>   Accommodation). Training variations inhibit accommodation and
>   ultimately the exhaustion stage of SAID. Polarizing training stimulus
>   around a target response between workouts can also help recovery
>   between workouts. These variations indirectly assists recovery since
>   the metabolic pathway are not taxed in the exact same way every
>   workout.   As a beginner, progress can be made most every workout.
>   Variation is inherent due to relatively rapid progress in the initial
>   phases of training (see Initial Level of Fitness). As progress slows,
>   subtle variations must be made in other ways for progress to continue
>   (see variation examples below).

Without variation, you'll tend to become “stale” and gains will plateau.  That includes any chance at a “squarer chest”.

Comment: In that quote though, it says "exercises and training loads". Assistance exercises are great, but I'd point to increasing the load as a point of variation. Benching 225 is a whole different bag of potatoes than 135, and I'd vote for someone to increase their strength. I can almost put money on people who are changing up their routines all the time as being smaller and weaker than those who correctly and scientifically crank up the volume in a progressive overload. +1 regardless.

Comment: @Eric Kaufman you raise a good point. Increasing the load is one of many ways to vary things.